# IIS Force SSL Redirect won't redirect root traffic

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, iis-10

I am using IIS 10 and I am attempting to redirect non ssl traffic to ssl. I've searched a lot and haven't found any other reports this specific, so I'm asking here.

The redirect is working for all urls except root traffic which is extremely weird.

For example if I put in `http://sitename.com` it does not redirect to `https`, however if I type in `http://sitename.com/index.html` it redirects to `https`.

My root page is an index.html page if that matters for any reason.

Web.config Code:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Force SSL" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www\.)?sitename\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://sitename.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
      ...
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

One other note, I've added this at the top level in IIS and it still doesn't work.

I've noticed in my definitions of rules in IIS on the site, it adds under the input column `URL path after '\'`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi well, while trying to get tracing installed I had to reinstall rewrite for it to show up as a module for tracing. And now redirection is working at the root ‍♂️. This whole thing has been weird. Because the exact same setup was working on my staging server, but wouldn't work on prod. but now it's working so, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your rule, “” always matched failed. I'm not sure what this result is when you match.

When I changed the patternSyntax="Wildcard" to regular expressions, it worked. So I suggest you to use regular expressions.

I also rewrite a new rule for you to redirect http to https. Https is used to determine whether the current request uses SSL. The values of https are On and Off, and On represents that the request uses SSL. More server variables can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables).
It always works even root traffic. You can use it.

```
<rule name="Force SSL" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="sitename.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://sitename.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

Here is the process in fail request tracing.

[image]

[image]